# How to replace || (two pipes) from a string with | (one) pipe

Tags: java, string

I am getting response for some images in json format within this tag:

> "xmlImageIds":"57948916||57948917||57948918||57948919||57948920||57948921||57948‌ ​922||57948923||57948924||57948925||57948926||5794892"

What i want to do is to separate each image id using .split("||") of the string class. Then append url with this image id and display it.

I have tried `.replace("\"|\"|","\"|");` but its not working for me. Please help.

EDIT: Shabbir, I tried to update your question according to your comments below. Please edit it again, if I didn't get it right.

Comment: Does it fail only with the pipe character? Have you tried other characters just to make sure?

Comment: yes it fails only with the pipe character

Comment: As a desperate measure, can you try a two-pass? Remove one of the bars first and go through a second time to extract the data, that is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
.replace("||", "|");
```

`|` is no special char.

However, if you are using `split()` or `replaceAll` instead of `replace()`, beware that you need to escape the pipe symbol as `\\|`, because these methods take a regex as parameter.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String in = "\"xmlImageIds\":\"57948916||57948917||57948918||57948919||57948920||57948921||57948‌922||57948923||57948924||57948925||57948926||5794892\"".replace("||", "|");

    String[] q = in.split("\"");
    String[] ids = q[3].split("\\|");
    for (String id : ids) {
        System.out.println("http://test/" + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should. Can you update your **question** to include your code and the input?

Comment: I am getting response for some images in json format within this tag "xmlImageIds":"57948916||57948917||57948918||57948919||57948920||57948921||57948922||57948923||57948924||57948925||57948926||5794892".What i want to do is to separate each image id using .split("||") of the string class .Then append url with this image id and display it.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what your problem is. You need to assign the result of `replace()`, not just call it.

```
String s = "foo||bar||baz";
s = s.replace("||", "|");
System.out.println(s);
```

I tested it, and just calling `s.replace("||", "|");` doesn't seem to modify the string; you have to assign that result back to `s`.

Edit: The Java 6 spec says "*Returns a new string* resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar." (the emphasis is mine).

Answer (score 1):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, `replace()` takes `char`s instead of `String`s. Perhaps you should try `replaceAll(String, String)` instead? Either that, or try changing your String (`""`) quotation marks into char (`''`) quotation marks.

Edit: I just noticed the overload for `replace()` that takes a `CharSequence`. I'd still give `replaceAll()` a try though.

Comment: `replaceAll()` takes a regex as its first argument, I'm not sure it is required in this case, is it?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's required. It will work, but it won't be the best way to do it. I just posted a new answer which I think (and hope) will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String pipe="pipes||";
    System.out.println("Old Pipe:::"+pipe);
    System.out.println("Updated Pipe:::"+pipe.replace("||", "|"));
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont remember how it works that method... but you can make your own:

```
String withTwoPipes = "helloTwo||pipes";
   for(int i=0; i<withTwoPipes.lenght;i++){
      char a = withTwoPipes.charAt(i);
      if(a=='|' && i<withTwoPipes.lenght+1){
         char b = withTwoPipes.charAt(i+1);
         if(b=='|' && i<withTwoPipes.lenght){
           withTwoPipes.charAt(i)='';
           withTwoPipes.charAt(i+1)='|';
         }
      }
   }
```

I think that some code like this should work... its not a perfect answer but can help...